# Tensorflow - Avoid Tensor Size Limit

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on an implementation of the FCN-32 net described in the [Long, Shelhamer paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf), but have run into a roadblock when upsampling. In order to upsample to original size, other [implementations](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn/blob/master/fcn32_vgg.py) use a `conv2d_transpose` layer with a bilinear filter w/kernel size 64x64. This works fine until you start using lots of classes.

For any number of classes > ~375, the `filters` variable in the transpose layer is > 2 gb ( 64 x 64 x (>375) x (>375) ) so Tensorflow complains and dies, saying

`ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.`

Is there any way to avoid this size limit? My first thought would be generative tensor, but I can't find any documentation on how to create if such a construct exists or is possible.

Comment: Are you sure 64x64 is the right shape? I think that should be much smaller, that's the kernel size, and 64x64 is crazy big. I see a reference to 14x14 in the paper (3x3 or 5x5 is more normal).

Comment: 64x64 is the correct shape when implementing FCN-32; kernel sizes for FCN-16/FCN-8 implementation use ksize 4x4 up to 16x16. See the caffe reference implementation for more details: https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/net.py

The large kernel size is necessary because it's getting upscaled by a factor of 32.

Comment: I believe that's the correct shape of the output of the layer, not of the actual kernel that produces the output, and the `filters` property refers to the weights, e.g. `[kernel_height, kernel_width, channels_in, channels_out]`. The kernel looks to be defined as a `[3,3]` kernel on line `5: def conv_relu(bottom, nout, ks=3, stride=1, pad=1):`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this more. `[3,3]` appears to be the default kernel size for all convolutional layers, but the layer to which I'm referring is the deconv layer upscore8. See lines 58-61: `n.upscore = L.Deconvolution(n.score_fr, convolution_param=dict(num_output=21, kernel_size=64, stride=32, ... `

Comment: I see, I believe you now, just had to be sure. :)  My first intuition then would be to split the output classes into multiple operations and concatenate them at the end. I haven't tried it, but I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work. Backprop will work just fine through the concat operation. It should be as trivial as creating two `conv2d_transpose` operations, each with half the classes and concat the results appropriately and continue to the loss function from there.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion! Will try this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the output classes into multiple operations and concatenate them at the end.

Backprop will work just fine through the concat operation. It should be as trivial as creating two `conv2d_transpose` operations, each with half the classes and concat the results appropriately and continue to the loss function from there.

Creating more than 2 `conv2d_transpose` operations as necessary will work just as well.

After thinking about this I'm confident it will work. If there's an issue let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I segmented the `conv2d_transpose` operation into 10 separate ops but Tensorflow apparently also has a 2GB graph size limit. Therefore performing these operations isn't possible with the library in its current state. :( Thanks again for the help!

For future readers, it's possible to implement the FCN-8 network with 1000 classes, but size limits make it impossible to do this in TF with FCN-16 and FCN-32.

Comment: Wait, what error do you get on graph size? I have models that push 10GB. But perhaps not in variables. This is surprising to me though.

Comment: ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.

Comment: But that's the `GraphDef`, definitions in the graph, all symbolic stuff. This shouldn't be impacted by `Variable` sizes as far as I understand. Check out this thread, seems to be the same issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2382  I guess you're creating a constant where you should be creating a variable somewhere. I reserve the right to be wrong though.

Comment: It looks like the GraphDef error was happening because when initializing 20 individual upsample layers (rather than one large one), all of the filters (size 64 x 64 x 50 x 1000) were getting implicitly converted to tensors. Fixed by converting the filters to a single tensor before passing to `conv2d_transpose` so that they're not converted to 20 different tensors. I then `concat` the 20 upsample layers and run argmax - this yields worse results than just reducing # logits to 20. Not sure why, but it takes so long to run this network that I'm it's not worth investigating to find out.