# Tensorflow returns ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
 def loadData():
      images_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'image_data')
      images = []
      for each in os.listdir(images_dir):
          images.append(os.path.join(images_dir,each))
      all_images = tf.convert_to_tensor(images, dtype = tf.string)
      images_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                                [all_images], batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
      return images_batch
```

returns

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

I'm trying to load about 11GB of images. How can I overcome those limitation?

Edit: Possbile duplicate:
You can split the output classes into multiple operations and concatenate them at the end is suggest, but I do not have multiple classes I can split.

Edit2:
Solutions to this problem suggest using placeholders. So now I'm not sure who to use placeholders in that case and where I can feed the array of images to tensorflow.

Here's a minimal version of my train function to show how I initialize the session.

```
def train():
     images_batch = loadData()
     sess = tf.Session()
     saver = tf.train.Saver()
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
     for i in range(EPOCH):
            train_image = sess.run(image_batch)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow - Avoid Tensor Size Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782521/tensorflow-avoid-tensor-size-limit)

Comment: What about convert to tensor with low amount of images ? Add for example 100 to images array, and after transform with convert_to_tensor, make same loop but with different photos, remember clean values from images array.

Comment: @deets I don't think since I'm not having output classes I could split into multiple operations and concatenate them at the end.

Comment: @deoncagadoes I could create smaller arrays, but in the end I need to combine them to one tensor?

Comment: Using convert_to_tensor will add your images to the computational graph, which is not what you want, you should be using placeholders for this.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes, I think you're spot on, that this isn't the best idea to do. I have edited my question to show more of the overall concept. Maybe you can share some insights on how to use a placeholder in my case and feed the data to the network.

Comment: I don't get your overall concept, are you trying to train a neural network or some kind of model? Placeholders are what everybody uses, every tensorflow tutorial covers them, so I don't get why you have trouble with them. The only difference I see is that when using placeholders, you have to manually produce batches.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro so just use normal X = tf.placeholder() and sess.run with feed_dict={X: images}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `convert_to_tensor` has the unexpected effect of adding your images to the computational graph, which has a hard limit of 2GB. If you hit this limit, you should reconsider how to feed images for the training process.

We already have a simple solution in TensorFlow, just use placeholders (`tf.placeholder`) and `feed_dict` in `session.run`. The only disadvantage in this case is that you have to produce batches of your data manually.